# JavaScript | AngularJS | UI-Router: Force Controller Execution Always

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

My scenario entails a route with a controller and view for state `app.foo`. When a user lands on this route via a menu-link, I would like UI-Router to **always** rerun/execute the controller -- as I have an event being dispatched here to get data from another module. The problem is that if User switches to `app.bar` and comes back to `app.foo`, this event never fires.

How can I force UI-Router to run this controller again?

Example:

```
.state('app.foo', {
    url: '/foo',
    alwaysReload: true
});
```

Is this possible?

Comment: did you tried `reload: true` option with `cache: false`? I'm not much sure..

Comment: The controller should fire each time the route change happens. Can you post your controller code?

Comment: Rob, I **could** post the code but it is quite a lot and I'm worried that it will obfuscate the simplicity of my question -- though, I appreciate you asking for it. Anyway, *Pankaj's suggestion was exactly what I needed!* Thank you both for contributing.

Comment: Pankaj, your suggestion worked perfectly. Would you mind posting this as an "Answer" with some more detail *and example code* so I can accept this?

Answer (score 2):

This is default behavior if you add a controller to the route definition, for ex:

```
    $stateProvider.state('app.foo', {
        url: '/foo',
        views: {
            "main": {
                controller: function ($scope) {
                      console.log('foo controller loaded.');
                },
                controllerAs: 'foo',
                templateUrl: 'foo/foo.tpl.html'
            }
        }
```

'foo controller loaded.' will always log when the 'app.foo' state is loaded.

Comment: This is not really a resolution to the question-scenario, but I'll upvote because its good to know. *I actually **do** have a controller on my state-config, but it is nested down within the `views: {...}` block*.